# Automapper Map related sources into one destination and flatten them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have following database objects:

```
public class LinkedContact
{
    public int LinkedContactID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ContactID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ContactTypeID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public virtual ContactType ContactType { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public Contact()
    {
        this.LinkedContact = new HashSet<LinkedContact>();
    }

    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LinkedContact> LinkedContact { get; set; }
}

public class ContactType
{
    public ContactType()
    {
        this.LinkedContact = new HashSet<LinkedContact>();
    }

    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LinkedContact> LinkedContact { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map it into following DTO

```
public class ContactDTO
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ContactTypeDTO ContactType { get; set; }
}

public class ContactTypeDTO
{
    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So basically, the `Contact Type` from `Linked Contact` should map to `Contact DTO`. End user will only see Contact View Model and is not aware of `Linked Contact` and hence the structure. Can anyone help me with the mapping configuration. I have tried the following with no luck

```
CreateMap<Contact, ContactDTO>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<LinkedContact, ContactDTO>()
CreateMap<ContactType, ContactTypeDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look through this link , there is a good [sample](https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/)

```
CreateMap<LinkedContact, ContactDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Contact.DisplayName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Contact.FirstName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Contact.LastName))
```

another option:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Contact, ContactDTO>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<ContactType, ContactTypeDTO>().ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<LinkedContact, ContactDTO>().ConvertUsing(src =>
                {
                    var contact = Mapper.Map<Contact, ContactDTO>(src.Contact);
                    contact.ContactType = Mapper.Map<ContactType, ContactTypeDTO>(src.ContactType);
                    return contact;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid using ForMember as I have 10-15 more properties. I tried using `CreateMap<LinkedContact, ContactDTO>().BeforeMap((src, dest, context) =>
            {
                dest = context.Mapper.Map<ContactDTO>(src.Contact);
            });` but to no avail

Comment: check second option

Comment: Awesome it worked. I just used an overload to avoid static Mapper. `CreateMap<LinkedContact, ContactDTO>().ConvertUsing((src, dest, context) =>
            {
                return context.Mapper.Map<ContactDTO>(src.Contact);
            });`

Comment: have i answered your question ? if yes, could you mark as resolved

Comment: Sorry but using the second option the mapping for `Contact Type` is lost

Answer (score 1):

Finally I used the below configuration which mapped both `Contact` and `Contact Type`. Leaving it here for people looking for answer to the same thing:

```
CreateMap<LinkedContact, ContactDTO>().ConvertUsing((src, dest, context) =>
{
     dest = context.Mapper.Map<ContactDTO>(src.Contact);
     dest.ContactType = context.Mapper.Map<ContactTypeDTO>(src.ContactType);
     return dest;
});
CreateMap<Contact, ContactDTO>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<ContactType, ContactTypeDTO>().ReverseMap();
```